# The code can only see the first one on the array

Tags: php, laravel

Can anyone tell me what's lacking in this code?

I wanted it to increment all of the coupons on the array but it only increments the first one

This is the controller

```
public function paidCount($user_id) {
   $meta = \App\EventBookingsMeta::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('meta_key', 'LIKE', 'used_coupons')->value('meta_value');
      if ( $meta ) {
        $decode = json_decode( $meta );
        if ( count( $decode ) > 0 ) {
            foreach( $decode as $coupon) {
            return \App\Coupon::find($coupon)->increment('no_paid');
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

this is what my "meta table" looks like

```
    user_id    meta_key           meta_value
    1          used_coupons       [3,5,9]
    2          used_coupons       [7, 8]
```

and this is the "coupons table"

```
    coupon_id    no_paid
    3            1
    5            0
    7            1
    8            0
    9            0
```

Only the 3 and 7 were incremented

Comment: you're `return`ing inside your `foreach` loop so only the first iteration will happen. Remove the `return` bit.

Comment: Thanks @BenSwinburne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `return` statement from your `foreach` loop. Calling a return will break out of `paidCount` on the first iteration.

Note the removed return in the example below.

```
public function paidCount($user_id) {
   $meta = \App\EventBookingsMeta::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('meta_key', 'LIKE', 'used_coupons')->value('meta_value');
      if ( $meta ) {
        $decode = json_decode( $meta );
        if ( count( $decode ) > 0 ) {
            foreach( $decode as $coupon) {
                \App\Coupon::find($coupon)->increment('no_paid');
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you very much